# Unity C# player object flickering

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Object I try to move flickers when I look up and move diagonally
[link to video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRR3e.jpg)

Cinemachine Freelook camera.

here is the code that moves the object:

```
direction = new Vector3(movementInput.x, 0f, movementInput.y).normalized;
if(direction.magnitude>=0.1f)
{
    float targetAngle=Mathf.Atan2(direction.x, direction.z)*Mathf.Rad2Deg+camera.eulerAngles.y;
    float angle = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetAngle,ref turnSmoothVelocity, turnSmoothTime);
    float targetAngleX = camera.eulerAngles.x * movementInput.y;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(targetAngleX,angle,0f);
    moveDir = Quaternion.Euler(targetAngleX, targetAngle, 0f) * Vector3.forward;
    characterController.Move(moveDir.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

It should work the way it does when I look down.

Comment: What about the code that renders the object?

Comment: Its not just a visual bug if I release input at the right time the object is indeed upside down or facing the wrong way

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like a typical problem when using EulerAngles. Try to avoid this feature and rewrite your code using only quaternions. Something like this:

```
Quaternion q = Quaternion.FromToRotation(start, end);
Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(start, q, time);
```